# Positive basis of non-negative orthant

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a question regarding positive linear basis. Doing my background research, I found that $\{a_1, \dots, a_k\}$ is a positive basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ there are $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k$ such that
$$
  \alpha_1 a_1 + \dots + \alpha_k a_k = x.
$$
Also $\{a_1,\dots,a_k\}$ should be positively linearly independent, i.e., no element of the basis should be a positive linear combination of others.

**Theorem.** Positive linear basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ has at least $n+1$ but at most $2n$ elements.

See, e.g., Davis Ch.: Theory of positive linear dependence, (1954).

My question is as follows. Let us consider not $\mathbb{R}^n$ but the space $\mathbb{R}_\uparrow^n$, i.e., vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ which all coordinates are non-negative and non-decreasing, i.e.,
$$
  (x_1,\dots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}_\uparrow^n \iff 0 \leq x_1 \leq \dots \leq x_n.
$$
A positive linear basis of $\mathbb{R}_\uparrow^n$ is any positively linearly independent subset of $\{0,1\}^n$ spanning the set $\mathbb{R}_\uparrow^n$. To give some examples of positive bases of $\mathbb{R}_\uparrow^n$:

- $\{(1,0,...,0), (0,1,0,...,0), ..., (0,...,0,1)\}$;
- $\{(0,...,0,1), (0,...,0,1,1), ..., (1,...,1)\}$;
- $\{(1,1,0,...,0), (0,1,1,0,...,0), ..., (0,...,0,1,1), (0,...,0,1)\}$.

I know that such basis should have at least $n$ elements. But I think that I need exactly $n$ elements. Do you think that the following hypothesis is true?

**Hypothesis.** Positive linear basis of $\mathbb{R}_+^n$ has exactly $n$ elements.

Can you please refer me to some work where the cone $\mathbb{R}_\uparrow^n$ and its positive bases are discussed? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, could you please be more precise about positive linear independence? Can you confirm that it is the same as Davis defines it? Also, I'm not convinced by the second and third examples. How would you form, say, $(0, 1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)$? (By the way, I assume $\alpha_i \ge 0$?)

Comment: If your definitions are what I think they are, the only positive bases for $\Bbb{R}^n_+$ will be positive scalar multiples of the standard basis; think about the exposed rays of the positive orthant.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and combined two questions into one... I corrected the post. I am interested in some cone and its positive basis.

Comment: Now I'm noticing that your basis elements do not belong to the given cone. Is that an issue? If not, then choosing a positive basis for $\Bbb{R}^n$ with more than $n$ vectors should be a counterexample (e.g. $\pm$ the standard basis). If you do require the basis to be taken from the cone, then I again think that you're going to be restricted to a selection of vectors from exposed rays of the cone.

Comment: @theo-bendit The basis elements are elements of {0,1}^n, i.e., they do not have to be from the cone but their coordinates are either zero, or one.